# constraining item difficulty in 2PL estimation using "ltm"

Tags: r, item-response-theory

I was planning to bridge IRT estimations of different tests using one particular item as an anchor. Currently, I am using the **ltm** package in R and am planning to do it using the option `constraint` under the function `ltm()`.

According to the documentation, this can be done as below:

> The two-parameter logistic model for the WIRS data
>   with the constraint that (i) the easiness parameter 
>   for the 1st item equals 1 and (ii) the discrimination
>   parameter for the 6th item equals -0.5

```
ltm(WIRS ~ z1, constr = rbind(c(1, 1, 1), c(6, 2, -0.5)))
```

After running the line above, it occurs to me that the difficulty parameter seems not to be constrained as specified: while difficulty of Item 1 is expected to be 1, it is estimated as -0.070. (On the other hand, the discrimination parameter estimation behaved as expected)

```
Call:
    ltm(formula = WIRS ~ z1, constraint = rbind(c(1, 1, 1), c(6, 2, -0.5)))
    Coefficients:
            Dffclt  Dscrmn
    Item 1  -0.070  14.259
    Item 2   0.121  -0.918
    Item 3   3.901   0.225
    Item 4  -4.267  -0.296
    Item 5   2.374   0.223
    Item 6   3.384   0.500
    Log.Lik: -3583.093
```

Am I misunderstanding this functionality, and, are there any other recommended ways to set up similar constraints for IRT estimates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About the functionality of ltm**

Note that `ltm` provides report for two different item parameterizations (for simplicity I focus on the case of *one* latent variable $z$; refer to the help page for detailed description):

$$logit(\pi_i)= \beta_{0i} + \beta_{1i}z \quad (1)$$ and $$logit(\pi_i)= a_{i}(z-b_{i}) \quad (2)$$

The estimation (and thereby parameter constraining) is based *exclusively* on the parameterization in Eqn (1). That is, using `ltm(..., constraint = rbind(c(1, 1, 1), ...))` the intercept $\beta_{0i}$ is set to 1.

Parameter reporting is done via the `print`-, `summary`- and `coef`-methods. The reported parameterization is chosen by the optional argument `IRT.param`. (Unfortunately,) in case of *one* (non-exponentiated) latent variable the reported parameters are in line with the parameterization in Eqn (2) by default. Note that there is a simple transformation for the easiness/difficulty parameters (discriminiation parameters are the same):

$$b_{i} = -\beta_{01}/\beta_{1i}$$

```
> mod <- ltm(WIRS ~ z1, constr = rbind(c(1, 1, 1), c(6, 2, -0.5)))
> (c1 <- coef(mod))
            Dffclt     Dscrmn
Item 1 -0.07013311 14.2586015
Item 2  0.12084500 -0.9178884
Item 3  3.90054017  0.2245981
Item 4 -4.26713242 -0.2957836
Item 5  2.37431636  0.2226061
Item 6  3.38428725  0.5000000
> (c2 <- mod$coefficients)
       (Intercept)         z1
Item 1   1.0000000 14.2586015
Item 2   0.1109222 -0.9178884
Item 3  -0.8760541  0.2245981
Item 4  -1.2621480 -0.2957836
Item 5  -0.5285374  0.2226061
Item 6  -1.6921436  0.5000000
> head(cbind(-c2[, 1]/c2[, 2], c2[, 2]), 1)
              [,1]    [,2]
Item 1 -0.07013311 14.2586
```

The standard errors of the constrained item parameters are `NA`

```
> summary(mod)

Call:
ltm(formula = WIRS ~ z1, constraint = rbind(c(1, 1, 1), c(6, 
    2, -0.5)))

...

Coefficients:
                value std.err   z.vals
Dffclt.Item 1 -0.0701      NA       NA
Dffclt.Item 2  0.1208  0.0787   1.5346
Dffclt.Item 3  3.9005  1.5996   2.4385
Dffclt.Item 4 -4.2671  1.7235  -2.4758
Dffclt.Item 5  2.3743  0.9179   2.5868
Dffclt.Item 6  3.3843  0.0166 203.7598
Dscrmn.Item 1 14.2586  9.2778   1.5369
Dscrmn.Item 2 -0.9179  0.1125  -8.1613
Dscrmn.Item 3  0.2246  0.0953   2.3574
Dscrmn.Item 4 -0.2958  0.1072  -2.7593
Dscrmn.Item 5  0.2226  0.0904   2.4631
Dscrmn.Item 6  0.5000      NA       NA

...
```

I agree that this behaviour is unexpected (and might even be unintended). A bug report might be useful.

**About the recommended ways for test equating**

There are several common ways to equate different tests, for example:

1. item parameter constraining (also possible in the R packages `TAM` and `mirt`),
2. common calibration of both tests and
3. item parameter transformation e.g. via mean-mean-linking (cf., R package `plink`).